# styled-components not responding

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

hey i am super new to react and redux and i am following a youtube video to make an app and i came across a part where i have to use custom css for a section. i followed the step exactly in the video but it didn't seems to work.
[image]

it seems like the overflow : hidden; and all other lines are simply not working. can anyone help me
[image]

this is how the frontend is looking but the "Content" should be in center. Please can anyone suggest anything.

**Note: already tried to install "styled-components" many time but it doesn't help.**

Comment: There's a typo in your CSS with `flex-direction`.

Comment: ya fixed that still not working

Comment: @JamieDixon can you suggest anything else...

Comment: With the exception of `height: 100uh;`  being invalid CSS -- should be `height: 100vh;`, I'm not able to replicate your issue: [Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/styled-components-simple-example-tfwgg). If you're still running into issues, please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

**To center your text you should do:**

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
text-align: center;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

This will make the container use your entire browser window size and then center it's contents.

Try inspecting your browser window to see how your container is sized.